# integer expression expected [bash does not understand .]

Tags: bash, integer, cpu-usage

I made a small script to kill PID's if they exceed expected cpu usage. It works, but there is a small problem.

Script:

```
while [ 1 ];
 do
  cpuUse=$(ps -eo %cpu | sort -nr | head -1)
  cpuMax=80
  PID=$(ps -eo %cpu,pid | sort -nr | head -1 | cut -c 6-20)

  if [ $cpuUse -gt $cpuMax ] ; then
   kill -9 "$PID"
   echo Killed PID $PID at the usage of $cpuUse out of $cpuMax

fi
exit 0
sleep 1;
done
```

It works if the integer is three digits long but fails if it drops to two and displays this:

./kill.sh: line 7: [: 51.3: integer expression expected

My question here is, how do I make bash understand the divider so it can kill processes under three digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably getting leading space in that variable. Try piping with tr to strip all spaces first:

```
cpuUse=$(ps -eo %cpu | sort -nr | head -1 | tr -d '[[:space:]]')
```

**Remove text after dot from `cpuUse` variable:**

```
cpuUse="${cpuUse%%.*}"
```

Also better to use quotes in if condition:

```
if [ "$cpuUse" -gt "$cpuMax" ] ; then
```

OR better use arithmetic operator `(( and ))`:

```
if (( cpuUse > cpuMax ));  then
```

Comment: Now it returns this: ./kill.sh: line 7: ((: 57.2 > 100 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".2 > 100 ")

Comment: Did you use tr to strip out spaces first? If `(( and ))` aren't available then use first option.

Comment: yes, i did, but its not the spaces which are causing this, its the dots between the digits since bash does not understand them and does not know how to compare them

Comment: BASH arithmetic doesn't support floating point maths. You need to convert `57.2` to `57` using **`cpuUse="${cpuUse%%.*}"`**

Answer (score 1):

As you see, bash doesn't grok non-integer numbers. You need to eliminate the decimal point and the following digits from `$cpuUse` before doing the comparison":

```
cpuUse=$(sed 's/\..*/' <<<$cpuUse)
```

However, this is really a job for `awk`. It will simplify much of what you're doing. Whenever you find yourself with `greps` of `greps`, or `head` and then `cuts`, you should be dealing with awk. Awk can easily combine these multiple piped seds, greps, cuts, heads, into a single command.

By the way, the *correct* `ps` command is:

```
 $ ps -eocpu="",pid=""
```

Using the `=""` will eliminate the heading and simply give you the CPU and PID.

Looking at your program, there's no real need to sort. You're simply looking for all processes above that `$cpuMax` threshold:

```
ps -eo %cpu="",pid="" | awk '$1 > 80 {print $2}'
```

That prints out your PIDs which are over your threshold. `Awk` automatically loop through your entire input line-by-line. Awk also automatically divides each line into columns, and assigns each a variable from `$1` and up. You can change the field divider with the `-F` parameter.

The above `awk` says look for all lines where the first column is above 80%, (the CPU usage) and print out the second column (the pid).

If you want some flexibility and be able to pass in different `$cpuMax`, you can use the `-v` parameter to set Awk variables:

```
ps -eo %cpu="",pid="" | awk -vcpuMax=$cpuMax '$1 > cpuMax {print $2}'
```

Now that you can pipe the output of this command into a while to delete all those processes:

```
pid=$(ps -eo %cpu="",pid="" | awk -vcpuMax=$cpuMax '$1 > cpuMax {print $2}')
if [[ -n $pid ]]
then
    kill -9 $pid
    echo "Killed the following processes:" $pid
fi
```